# mootools "this" in each?

Tags: javascript, mootools

Probably misunderstanding something simple, but i can't seem to get this to work.

I want to: go trough each img element in "wrapper", and strip all html from the title attribute (with stripTags() from mootools more). I get the error:

"this.get is not a function"

here is the code:

```
$('wrapper').getElements('img').each(function() {

    var oldAlt = this.get('title').stripTags();
    this.setProperty('alt', oldAlt);

});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('wrapper').getElements('img').each(function(el) {
    var oldAlt = el.get('title').stripTags();
    el.setProperty('alt', oldAlt);

});
```

this does not refer to the looping element -- the first argument to the .each callback function is `element` passed, the second is `index` (opposite to jquery where index is first).

Answer (score -2):

The other option is to bind the `this` variable

```
$('wrapper').getElements('img').each(function() {

    var oldAlt = this.get('title').stripTags();
    this.setProperty('alt', oldAlt);

}).bind(this);
```

The extra `.bind(this)` basically means, in the scope inside the  each function, the variable `this` is bound to whatever value is refers to outside. (like passing the variable into the scope). If you have need to access the normal this pointer as well, as the outside reference, you should go with an option such as @Chetan's answer

Comment: er, he wants to loop through all the img elements and set a different alt tag on them. what exactly would you be achieving by binding the callback to `this` when you don't even know the context of the snippet for this code block (this can be window or a class instance or even an anchor element that has triggered a click event...).

Comment: Not mentioning that bind should be attached to the anonymous function instead. each has also a place for bind object: each(fn, bind_object), where bind_object here would be `this`